# Нужно получить строку, содержащую цепочку вызывающих модулей

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, c++-cli

Всем привет и заранее спасибо.
Мне нужно получить строку, содержащую цепочку вызывающих модулей:

- Консольное приложение C# exe (C# 1.exe), которое содержит только функцию Main, в которой вызывается функция FunctionDLL() библиотеки C# 2.dll

  Main()
  {
  FunctionDLL()
  }
- Библиотека C# (C# 2.dll), которая содержит одну функцию FunctionDLL (), эта функция вызывает функцию GetModulePaths () из библиотеки C ++ C ++ 3.dll

  public static string FunctionDLL()
  {
  return GetModulePaths();
  }
- Библиотека C++ (C++ 3.dll), которая содержит одну функцию GetModulePaths () и возвращает строку, содержащую цепочку вызывающих модулей. Мне нужно получить список полных путей к модулям строгого порядка, например::

  "C:\Projects\C# 1.exe
  C:\Projects\C# 2.dll
  C:\Projects\C++ 3.dll"

**РЕШЕНО**
невозможно получить из неуправляемого кода стектрэйс (и пути к вызывающим модулям соответсвенно) на управляемый код, который его вызывает.
максимум что я смог получить из неуправляемой С++ DLL - это путь к .Net модулю clr.dll
из управляемого - можно.
смотри пример тут:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17386/Get-the-calling-module-that-invoked-your-function

Comment: Что вы патались сделать и в чём возникла проблема?

Comment: @Maverick Похоже, что Вам просто нужно взять текущий стектрейс (Environment.StackTrace) и привести в удобный Вам вид.

Comment: @KoVadim Я же четко написал, что нужно получить цепочку вызывающих модулей в С++ DLL. причем тут Environment.StackTrace ?

Comment: в с++ или с++/cli c# ?

Comment: @ KoVadim через Environment.StackTrace я могу получить пути к исходным файлам, откуда произошел вызов, но не абсолютные пути к модулям, типа "C:\Projects\C# 1.exe C:\Projects\C# 2.dll C:\Projects\C++ 3.dll".  Но это все касается только реализации с .Net ! Я же четко написал, что надо получить строку, содержащую цепочку вызывающих модулей внутри С++ DLL библиотеки. причем тут Environment.StackTrace ?

Comment: @KoVadim  в C++.   Вызов С++ DLL производится через [DllImport("3.dll", EntryPoint = "GetModulePaths", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]        
        public static extern string GetModulePaths();

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то это c++/cli. Поэтому, пока мой комментарий остается почти в силе.

Comment: 1-ый модуль C# exe, 2-ой модуль C# dll, 3-ий модуль C++ DLL (НЕ CLI) - обычная ДЛЛка на С++

Comment: в этом случае ищите любую либу, которая умеет делать стектрейс, если она умеет получать имена модулей - уже хорошо, нет, придется по адресам восстанавливать

Comment: я уже сам написал код со стекТрэйсом , используя ф-ию CaptureStackBackTrace(), получаю список адресов фрэймов, по этим адресам получаю с помощью ф-ии GetModuleHandleEx() хэндлы модулей и уже по хэндлам через GetModuleFileNameA() - пути к модулям. Но я смог получить путь только к CLR-модулю ДотНета:  in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

Comment: т.е. я смог получить стектрэйс до управляемого кода с CLR - а вот как из него получить хэндл второй C# DLL -  я не знаю пока.

Comment: кажется теперь стало понятно: невозможно получить из неуправляемого кода стектрэйс (и пути к вызывающим модулям соответсвенно) на управляемый код, который его вызывает

Answer (score 0):

Невозможно получить из неуправляемого кода стектрэйс (и пути к вызывающим модулям соответсвенно) на управляемый код, который его вызывает.
Для решения проблемы можно создать C++ библиотеку смешанного типа (mixed type, Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)).
Здесь анализируется, является ли полученный с помощью метода CaptureStackBackTrace() модуль модулем управляемого кода, это происходит с помощью вызова метода управляемого кода (С++/CLI) IsDotNetRuntime.
И если это модуль управляемого кода, то с помощью метода GetDotNetCallerFileName() получаем путь к нему.
Вот пример управляемого кода в этой библиотеке:

```
int GetDotNetCallerFileName(string& module)
{

    int res = FALSE;
    try
    {
        Assembly^ callerAssembly = Assembly::GetCallingAssembly();
        if (callerAssembly == nullptr)
            return FALSE;
        String^ sysdir = System::Runtime::InteropServices::RuntimeEnvironment::GetRuntimeDirectory();
        //skip all .net framework assemblies and calls from the same assembly

        String^ strCallerPath = callerAssembly->Location;
        String^ directoryName = nullptr;
        if (strCallerPath != nullptr)
            directoryName = Path::GetDirectoryName(strCallerPath) + "\\";

        while (directoryName != nullptr && (String::Compare(sysdir, directoryName, true) == 0)
            || callerAssembly == Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly())
        {
            strCallerPath = nullptr;
            callerAssembly = callerAssembly->GetCallingAssembly();
            directoryName = nullptr;
            if (strCallerPath != nullptr)
                directoryName = Path::GetDirectoryName(strCallerPath) + "\\";
            strCallerPath = callerAssembly->Location;
        }


        pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(strCallerPath);
        size_t convertedChars = 0;
        size_t  sizeInBytes = ((strCallerPath->Length + 1) * 2);
        errno_t err = 0;
        char* ch = (char*)malloc(sizeInBytes);

        err = wcstombs_s(&convertedChars,
            ch, sizeInBytes,
            wch, sizeInBytes);
        if (err == 0)
            module = ch;
        free(ch);
        res = TRUE;
    }
    catch (Exception^ e)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(e->Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return res;
}

BOOL IsDotNetRuntime(char* callerModulePath)
{
    //check for .net runtime path
    String^ path = Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)callerModulePath);
    String^ directoryName;
    directoryName = Path::GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\";
    String^ sysdir = RuntimeEnvironment::GetRuntimeDirectory();
    if (String::Compare(sysdir, directoryName, true) == 0)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Тут С++ ... ннада!!!

Comment: @Majestio Что вы хотели выразить этим комментарием? Автор явно пишет, что на чистом С++ это невозможно, поэтому используется С++/CLI. Что логично, так как С++/CLI специально создан для интеграции С++ с .NET.

Comment: Хотя меня тут посетила мысль, что может через Unmanaged Debugging  API (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/) это можно как-нибудь сделать в чистом С++

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, тогда либо тег `с++` менять, либо не использовать `.net`.